# Multiple sockets receiving the same randomly generated word - Node.js/Socket.io/Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I would like to generate a random word from an array and then change the innerHTMl of an element to that word. However I would like this to happen so that multiple client browsers are receiving the same word.
Currently every browser is receiving a random word however not the same random word. I understand why this is happening - the function is being called in every browser and therefore generating a unique random word to that browser. How do I ensure that the same randomly generated word is sent out to each individual browser?

Code below:

Index.Js (server side)

```
var express = require('express')
var socket = require('socket.io') 

//App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('listening to requests on port 8000')
});


//static files
app.use(express.static('public'));


//socket setup
var io = socket(server);

//listening for connection event from browser on connection fires callback function (backend)
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id)

    //Listening for colorchange (click event from front end)
    socket.on('colorChange', function(){
        io.sockets.emit('colorChange')
    })
});
```

button.js Client side

```
// Make connection (socket for front end)
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

let wordList = ['cat', 'dog', 'skunk']

//Accessing DOM
let td1 = document.getElementById("td1")


//Send click to server
td1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('colorChange');
});

//Listen for events from back end to execute on front end 
socket.on('colorChange', function() {
   td1.style.color = "red"
   td1.innerHTML = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)] //ATTEMPT TO GENERATE RANDOM WORD
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Button Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="grid">
        <tr>
            <td id="td1">Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="/button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If no random word previously generated, generate a word, save it to the db, and send it all requesting clients?

Comment: you can try generating a queue of random words and then keep a track of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is what you can do:

Index.Js (server side)

```js
var express = require('express')
var socket = require('socket.io') 

//App setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8000, function(){
    console.log('listening to requests on port 8000')
});


//static files
app.use(express.static('public'));


//socket setup
var io = socket(server);
var wordList = ['cat', 'dog', 'skunk'];
var selectedWord = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
// when you run server,
// you will have a selectedWord

//listening for connection event from browser on 
// connection fires callback function (backend)
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
    // everytime someone connecteds send to single user what selectedWord
    // currently is
    socket.emit('colorChange', selectedWord);

    //Listening for colorchange (click event from front end)
    socket.on('colorChange', function(){
        // when someone wants to change 
        selectedWord = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
        // we are gonna select a new one and send it to everyone
        io.sockets.emit('colorChange', selectedWord);
        // so on button.js where you listen this event
        // it's gonna set new randomly selected word for every user :=)
    })
});
```

button.js Client side

```js
// Make connection (socket for front end)
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

//Accessing DOM
let td1 = document.getElementById("td1")

//Send click to server
td1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('colorChange');
});

//Listen for events from back end to execute on front end 
socket.on('colorChange', function(word) {
   td1.style.color = "red"
   td1.innerHTML = word;
});
```

Edit:
There is also other way that you can create from frontend side and send it to server and broadcast to everyone is also acceptable for your example i'm guessing :)

Comment: How would you create from the front end?

Comment: So first: move `wordList` to frontend again, second: while emitting send the word with it `socket.emit('colorChange', selectedWord);` and third broadcast it :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!